# Why isn't the physics working the way I want it to?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Okay, so in my game I have a block of code that spawns a sprite ('enemy') every x amount of time. It spawns the sprite up high and the sprite falls down.

**What should happen is this:** The sprite falls down, it touches the ground or another enemy, then it changes to static so it can't be moved.

**What happens is this:** Sometimes it works, but sometimes (especially when the x amount of time is smaller and the sprites spawn more often) the sprite suddenly changes to static while it is still in the air.

Why is this happening?

**Here's some code:**

*in GameScene.m, in createSceneContents, a method that is called by didMoveToView:*

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

SKSpriteNode *bottom = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] size:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 10)];
bottom.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, 0);
bottom.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:bottom.size];
bottom.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
bottom.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
bottom.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = self.bottomCategory;
bottom.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = self.enemyCategory;

[self spawnObject];
[self addChild:self.world];
[self.world addChild:bottom];
```

*in spawnObject, a method that gets called by createSceneContents:*

```
if (self.isPaused == NO){

    self.spawningSpeed = 1;
    self.enemyData = [[Enemy alloc]init];
    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:self.spawningSpeed];
    SKAction *run = [SKAction runBlock:^{

        SKSpriteNode *aNewEnemy = [self.enemyData createEnemyWithSize:self.customUnit andWidth:self.frame.size.width andHeight:self.frame.size.height + self.player.position.y andPlayerPosition:self.player.position.x];
        aNewEnemy.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
        aNewEnemy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = self.enemyCategory;
        aNewEnemy.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = self.enemyCategory | self.bottomCategory;
        aNewEnemy.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = self.enemyCategory | self.bottomCategory;
        [self.world addChild:aNewEnemy];



    }];
    SKAction *action = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[wait,run]]];
    [self runAction:action withKey:@"action"];
```

*in createEnemyWithSize:andWidth:andHeight:andPlayerPosition:, in Enemy.m:*

```
self.enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"block.png"];
self.enemy.size = CGSizeMake(size - 5, size - 5);
self.enemy.name = @"fallingEnemy";
self.enemy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(size - 1, size - 1)];
self.enemy.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
self.enemy.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;

int column1 = width/7;
int column2 = column1 * 2;
int column3 = column1 * 3;
int column4 = column1 * 4;
int column5 = column1 * 5;
int column6 = column1 * 6;
int halfAColumn = column1/2;

if (position > 0 && position < column1) {
    self.enemy.position = CGPointMake(halfAColumn, height - size);

}else if (position > column1 && position < column2) {
    self.enemy.position = CGPointMake((column2-halfAColumn), height - size);

}else if (position > column2 && position < column3) {
    self.enemy.position = CGPointMake((column3-halfAColumn), height - size);

}else if (position > column3 && position < column4) {
    self.enemy.position = CGPointMake((column4-halfAColumn), height - size);

}else if (position > column4 && position < column5) {
    self.enemy.position = CGPointMake((column5-halfAColumn), height - size);

}else if (position > column5 && position < column6) {
    self.enemy.position = CGPointMake((column6-halfAColumn), height - size);

}else if (position > column6 && position < width) {
    self.enemy.position = CGPointMake((width-halfAColumn), height - size);

}

return self.enemy;
```

*in didBeginContact, in GameScene.m:*

```
SKPhysicsBody *enemyBodyA, *bottomBodyA, *enemyBodyB, *bottomBodyB;
if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == self.enemyCategory) {
        enemyBodyA = contact.bodyA;

}else if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == self.bottomCategory) {

        bottomBodyA = contact.bodyA;

}
    if (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == self.enemyCategory) {
        enemyBodyB = contact.bodyB;

}else if (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == self.bottomCategory) {

        bottomBodyB = contact.bodyB;

}

        if (enemyBodyA == contact.bodyA && enemyBodyB == contact.bodyB) {

        [self.enemyData changeBlock];


        NSLog(@"Change1");
    }
    if (contact.bodyA == enemyBodyA && contact.bodyB == bottomBodyB) {
        NSLog(@"Change2");
        [self.enemyData changeBlock];


    }
    if (contact.bodyB == enemyBodyB && contact.bodyA == bottomBodyA) {
        NSLog(@"Change3");
        [self.enemyData changeBlock];


    }
```

*in changeBlock, in Enemy.m:*

```
-(void)changeBlock {
self.enemy.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
self.enemy.name = @"staticEnemy";
}
```

Bitmask values in createSceneContents:

```
self.playerCategory = 1;
self.enemyCategory = 2;
self.edgeCategory = 4;
self.bottomCategory = 8;
```

Comment: What is self.enemyData on which you are calling the changeBlock method in the contact delegate?

Comment: an Object of the Enemy class

Comment: You need to stop referencing the created enemy node as a property of the enemyData object. Use the body.node property in the contact delegate to get the node in contact. The current way is messing it up. I am writing an answer, and shall post it in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been extremely frustrated for the past 2 hours, you have really helped me!

Comment: In the meantime, could you post code where you have set the bitmask values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be losing a reference to the enemy which has not received a contact before another is spawned. Hence a few changes are needed. You do not need the self.enemy property in the enemy class at all.

First of all, modify the changeBlock method so it can be performed on any block which is passed as a parameter.

```
-(void)changeBlock:(SKSpriteNode*)block {
    block.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    block.name = @"staticEnemy";
}
```

And then clean up the contact delegate method.

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

    //This is a useful technique for organising bodies in the contact delegate
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA;
        secondBody = contact.bodyB;
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB;
        secondBody = contact.bodyA;
    }
    //Since enemyCategory < bottomCategory, the firstBody is an enemy node, and second either an enemy or bottom node

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == self.enemyCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == self.bottomCategory) {
        [self.enemyData changeBlock: (SKSpriteNode*)firstBody.node];
    } else if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == self.enemyCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == self.enemyCategory) {
        [self.enemyData changeBlock: (SKSpriteNode*)firstBody.node];
        [self.enemyData changeBlock: (SKSpriteNode*)secondBody.node];
    }
}
```

I am not sure what your game is about so change is as you wish. But I hope you get the idea.

Comment: It gives me a warning when I pass spritenodes to changeblock because the bodies are just nodes? Should I change it or ignore it? The way you organize the bodies is really clever. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah it should not make a difference either way. Do what is required to remove the warnings.

Comment: I also think you made a little mistake. You are checking wether first/secondBody are equal to a category instead of first/secondBody.categoryBitMask